# Receive all data at once from azure topic

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to fetch data from azure Service Bus topic with python, but as per below example i can read data only one by one in for loop, is there any way through which i can read all data at one go, and mark that record at completed

this below code is working, but it fetch data one by one

```
with servicebus_client:
receiver = servicebus_client.get_subscription_receiver(topic_name=TOPIC_NAME, subscription_name=SUBSCRIPTION_NAME, max_wait_time=5)
with receiver:
    for msg in receiver:
        print("Received: " + str(msg))
        receiver.complete_message(msg)
```

i am trying in this way but it is throwing error

```
with servicebus_client:
    receiver = servicebus_client.get_subscription_receiver(topic_name=TOPIC_NAME, subscription_name=SUBSCRIPTION_NAME, max_wait_time=5)
    with receiver:
      with open('/tmp/abc.json', 'w') as fp:
          fp.write(str(receiver))
          receiver.complete_message(receiver)
```

error

```
Parameter 'message' must be of type ServiceBusReceivedMessage
```

but in file also data is not written some object is written in file

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying in this way but it is throwing error

Your question has nothing to do with azure functions or azure service bus. This is a python problem.

This error is reported because the object passed in by receiver.complete_message(ServiceBusReceivedMessage message) is incorrect(It requires a specific ServiceBusReceivedMessage type element, but you pass in a generator.).

In addition, the receiver is a generator. Of course you have to use a for loop to get specific information. Simply put, one is a collection and the other is an element. Another point, if you design your code this way, all your information will fail to process because they are never completed.